# How can I refactor my stateful React component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a stateful `Key` component that represents a Key in a Keyboard like so:

```
        import React from 'react';

        class Key extends React.Component {

            constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.state = {
                    id: props.id,
                    customClass: props.customClass,
                    value: props.value,
                    onAction: props.onAction,
                    active: false
                };

                this.handleAction = this.handleAction.bind(this);
                this.resetActiveState = this.resetActiveState.bind(this);
            }

            handleAction(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                this.setState ({
                    active: true
                });
                this.state.onAction(this.state.value);

    //remove key pressed effect after 150 ms by resetting active state
                _.delay(() => this.resetActiveState() , 150);
            }

            resetActiveState() {
                this.setState ({
                    active: false
                });
            }

            render() {
//conditionalProps is empty when active is false.
                let conditionalProps = {};
                let className = `default-btn ${this.state.customClass}`;
                let displayValue = this.state.value;

    //enable css attribute selector
                if (this.state.active){
                    conditionalProps['data-active'] = '';
                }
                    return (
                        <button id={this.state.id} key={this.state.id} className={className}
                                data-value={this.state.value} {...conditionalProps} onTouchStart={this.handleAction}>
                            {displayValue}
                        </button>
                    );

            }
        }

        Key.defaultProps = {
            customClass: '',
            onAction: (val) => {}
        };

        export default Key;
```

- `onTouchStart` is used to detect a touch event.
- `onTouchStart` handler changes `active` state to `true`.
- `Component` re-renders with the appropriate css to give key clicked
  effect.
- After 150ms, `active` state is set to false using `resetActiveState()`.
- Component re-renders without the key clicked effect css.

`conditionalProps` attribute is used to conditionally add css styles (using css attribute selector) to achieve 'key pressed' look in the rendered component.

This works as expected but I was wondering if it would be possible to refactor the component so I can extract the logic to maybe a parent component which I can then extend using the Key component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a perfect use case for a [Higher Order Component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html).

This will allow you to abstract much of the functionality and pass it down to stateless components as props.

The React official docs do a great job of explaining how to use HOCs.

Comment: Thank you for the response. This looks very promising! 

Is it also possible to maybe write a parent component with reusable logic and extending it in a child component? HOC seems like the way to go; but I would also like to know the drawbacks of this approach against HOC.

Comment: If you mean inheritance, the React team has been [very clear](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) that they prefer composition over inheritance. However, a parent component supplying props to a child component is really just component composition, and an HOC is really just a more powerful way of composing components.

Comment: I completed a HOC implementation, everything works great. But I ran into one dilemma that I think deserves a new question which I posted here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43471019/access-wrapped-component-function-from-hoc 
Please have a look if time permits :)