# Access wrapped component function from HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Imagine a HOC for touch behavior that detects key touch events through onTouchStart. Now the wrapped components using the touch HOC, will have its own handler logic. How can my HOC component, call the wrapped components handler functions?

Just to get an idea, here's what I need. On research I found [this](https://github.com/gajus/react-outside-event) that uses ref to call the target component. I was wondering if there are better ways to accomplish this.

**TouchBehavior HOC**

```
const TouchBehavior = (WrappedComponent) =>

    class extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                active: false,
            };
            this.handleAction = this.handleAction.bind(this);
            this.setActiveState = this.setActiveState.bind(this);
            this.resetActiveState = this.resetActiveState.bind(this);
        }

        handleAction(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.setActiveState();
            //call wrapped component specific handler logic here
            _.delay(() => this.resetActiveState() , 150);
        }

        setActiveState() {
            this.setState ({
                active: true
            });
        }

        resetActiveState() {
            this.setState ({
                active: false
            });
        }

        render() {
            let touchBehaviorProps = {
                onTouchStart: this.handleAction
            };
            return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} touchBehaviorProps={touchBehaviorProps} />
        }
    };
```

**Wrapped component**

```
class Button extends React.Component {

 componentSpecificHandlerLogic(){
  //logic goes here
 }

 render () {
  return <button {..this.props.touchBehaviorProps}></button>
 }
}
```

Comment: Instead of invoking callbacks, you can send touch state as props to the component. This will result in the wrapped component reacting to the touch state in whatever fashion it wants. Also this will work with stateless components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever possible, I would try not to pull logic back up the tree, but rather pass more down.

There are probably many ways to achieve this, but one option I see in this case is to change the prop provided to the wrapped component to be a function that constructs the handler for them with the provided custom logic.

**TouchBehavior HOC**

```
const TouchBehavior = (WrappedComponent) =>

    class extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                active: false,
            };
            this.handleAction = this.handleAction.bind(this);
            this.setActiveState = this.setActiveState.bind(this);
            this.resetActiveState = this.resetActiveState.bind(this);
        }

        handleAction(e, customHandler) {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.setActiveState();
            customHandler();
            _.delay(() => this.resetActiveState() , 150);
        }

        setActiveState() {
            this.setState ({
                active: true
            });
        }

        resetActiveState() {
            this.setState ({
                active: false
            });
        }

        render() {
            let touchBehaviorProps = (customHandler) => ({
                onTouchStart: (e) => this.handleAction(e, customHandler)
            });
            return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} touchBehaviorProps={touchBehaviorProps} />
        }
    };
```

**Wrapped Component**

```
class Button extends React.Component {

 componentSpecificHandlerLogic(){
  //logic goes here
 }

 render () {
  return <button {...this.props.touchBehaviorProps(componentSpecificHandlerLogic)}></button>
 }
}
```

Comment: brilliant. Works perfect